# WPF designer, target x64 platform: Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedAssemblyException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

So I have a WPF app, I have to create it for both x64 and x86 due hardware usage. But when I change the target platform to x64 and try to open a .xaml file, it shows below error message in the designer.

When I change it back to Any CPU, it is OK, I have the designer back. In both platform targets the app runs fine.

```
Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.SimpleUniverse.Microsoft.MetadataReader.ITypeUniverse.ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName name)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.SimpleUniverse.Microsoft.MetadataReader.ITypeUniverse.ResolveAssembly(Module scope, Token tokenAssemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.ResolveTypeRef(ITypeReference typeReference)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeReference.GetResolvedTypeWorker()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeProxy.GetResolvedType()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeProxy.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(String key, IAssembly assembly, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Cache()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(String key, IAssembly assembly, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Cache()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(String key, IAssembly assembly, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.GetType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Cache()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.Initialize(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(String key, IAssembly assembly, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(ClrNamespaceIdentifier clrNamespaceIdentifier, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.GetType(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.GetType(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.DocumentXmlnsDefinitionMap.GetType(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.ResolveTypeInternal(ITypeResolver typeResolver, IXmlNamespaceTypeResolver xmlNamespaceTypeResolver, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.ResolveType(ITypeResolver typeResolver, IXmlNamespaceTypeResolver xmlNamespaceTypeResolver, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetTypeId(ITypeResolver typeResolver, DocumentXmlnsDefinitionMap documentNamespaces, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean instantiateUnrecognizedTypes, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetTypeId(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetTypeId(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlNamespaceResolver, String fullTypeName, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser.ParseMarkupExtension(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlNamespaceResolver, IType valueType, String text, Int32 attributeValueOffset)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser.GetPropertyValue(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlNamespaceResolver, TypeConverter typeConverter, IType valueTypeId, String value, Boolean removeEscapeCharacters, XmlAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.SetProperty(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlAttribute attribute, IProperty propertyKey)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseStyleOrTemplate(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, ITypeId type, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseRootElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.Parse(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlDocumentReference xmlDocumentReference, XmlDocument xmlDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseInternal(XamlParserContext parserContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlLanguageService.ParseDocument(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.SceneMarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, IUndoService undoService, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateMarkupDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, IHostTextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean cloneBufferToStandalone, Boolean suppressUI, SceneDocument originalSceneDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OpenDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextBase.OpenProjectDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.DocumentModel.XamlProjectContext.FindApplicationDocumentForContext(XamlProjectContext xamlProjectContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.DocumentModel.XamlProjectContext.get_LocalApplication()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.DocumentModel.XamlProjectContext.get_Application()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.SceneDocument.GetApplicationDocument(IProjectContext activeContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.View.ViewRootResolver.GetView(IDocumentRoot documentRoot, Boolean hidden)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateAndOpenViewInternal(SceneDocument document, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean activate, Boolean ensureOpenInHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

At first, some errors showed up as well (while it could still run). Those errors told me that I had some Portable Libraries set to x64 as well. So I've set them back to Any CPU separately in the Configuration Manager. Then some warnings appeared about mismatches, but that soon disappeared after a clean build.

Maybe it is worth noting that the Styles are in a different assembly, but changing this to Any CPU or to x64 as well does not have any effect. I'm also using [Metro](http://mahapps.com/) as base classes for my windows.

Comment: hey @CularBytes, you ever get this to work? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Nope, I have read elsewhere that it is still a bug and you just have to switch back to Any CPU. Currently I am actually facing a much larger bug where it doesn't load the designer at all -.-